# C# WinForms: Make panel scrollbar invisible

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, scrollbar, panel

I have a `panel1` with `AutoScroll = true`.I have to make `panel1` scroll with `btnUp` and `btnDown`. So far I've made what I was asked for

```
private void btnUpClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (panel1.VerticalScroll.Value - 55 > 0)
        panel1.VerticalScroll.Value -= 55;
    else  panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = 0;
}

private void btnDownClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.VerticalScroll.Value += 55;
}
```

But now I need to hide `Scrollbar` or make it invisible. I tried

```
panel1.VerticalScroll.Visible = false;
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas guys?

Comment: That's what `AutoScroll=true` does...gives you a scrollbar automatically.  You can't do both unless you take over the behavior entirely.

Comment: Yeah I was afraid of that. What can I do ?

Comment: Well, if you want it bad enough, you could create a new control inheriting from `Panel` and then implement your own scrolling.  Not trivial, of course, but doable.  Lots of examples out there for rolling your own scroll with a timer and such.

Comment: @user3683349 I gave you the whole solution, just copy paste it. Check it out ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I've done the working example of this for you. All you have to do is to change the max value depending on the total size of all the items inside your panel.

---

**Form code:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int location = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set position on top of your panel
        pnlPanel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, 0);

        // Set maximum position of your panel beyond the point your panel items reach.
        // You'll have to change this size depending on the total size of items for your case.
        pnlPanel.VerticalScroll.Maximum = 280;
    }

    private void btnUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (location - 20 > 0)
        {
            location -= 20;
            pnlPanel.VerticalScroll.Value = location;
        }
        else
        {
            // If scroll position is below 0 set the position to 0 (MIN)
            location = 0;
            pnlPanel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, location);
        }
    }

    private void btnDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (location + 20 < pnlPanel.VerticalScroll.Maximum)
        {
            location += 20;
            pnlPanel.VerticalScroll.Value = location;
        }
        else
        {
            // If scroll position is above 280 set the position to 280 (MAX)
            location = pnlPanel.VerticalScroll.Maximum;
            pnlPanel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, location);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Picture example:**

[image: Pic1]
[image: Pic2]

You have to set `AutoScroll` option to **False** on your panel. I hope you understand what I've done and will get your panel running the way you want. Feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: how to set  pnlPanel.VerticalScroll.Maximum to auto? I populate panel with button I want its maxscroll size to be auto

Comment: I know I am late supposing you didn't find a way so far... To do that you have to get the count of controls contained in your panel and multiply it by the hight of controls and top bottom margins and set the maximum scroll value to that ending result and change it every time a control is added!

Answer (score 5):

The Panel control takes on the duty you gave it by setting AutoScroll to true pretty serious.  This *always* includes displaying the scrollbar gadget if it is necessary.  So what you tried cannot work, hiding the vertical scrollbar forces Panel to recalculate layout since doing so altered the client area.  It will of course discover that the scrollbar is required and promptly make it visible again.

The code that does this, Panel inherits it from ScrollableControl, is *internal* and cannot be overridden.  This was intentional.

So using AutoScroll isn't going to get you anywhere.  As an alternative, do keep in mind what you really want to accomplish.  You simply want to move controls up and down.  Easy to do, just change their Location property.  That in turn is easiest to do if you put the controls on *another* panel, big enough to contain them.  Set its AutoSize property to True.  And implement you buttons' Click event handlers by simply changing that panel's Location property:

```
private const int ScrollIncrement = 10;

private void ScrollUpButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int limit = 0;
    panel2.Location = new Point(0, 
        Math.Min(limit, panel2.Location.Y + ScrollIncrement));
}

private void ScrollDownButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int limit = panel1.ClientSize.Height - panel2.Height;
    panel2.Location = new Point(0, 
        Math.Max(limit, panel2.Location.Y - ScrollIncrement));
}
```

Where panel1 is the outer panel and panel2 is the inner one that contains the controls.  Be careful when you use the designer to put controls on it, it has a knack for giving them the wrong Parent.  Be sure to use the View + Other Windows + Document Layout helper window so you can see this going wrong.  After you filled it, set its AutoSizeMode property to GrowAndShrink so it snaps to its minimum size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
panel.AutoScroll = true;
panel.VerticalScroll.Enabled = false;
panel.VerticalScroll.Visible = false;
```

Edit:

Actually when AutoScroll = true; It will take care of hscroll and vscroll automatically and you wont be able to change it. I found this on Panel.AutoScroll Property on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll.aspx)

```
 AutoScroll maintains the visibility of the scrollbars automatically. Therefore, setting the HScroll or VScroll property to true has no effect when AutoScroll is enabled.
```

You may try this to workaround this problem, I have copied it from this [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6b9c2c72-e91a-40f0-a835-c12328490c0c/how-to-scroll-without-a-scrollbar-or-make-scrollbar-invisible?forum=winforms).

#### Behavior Observations 1:

If AutoScroll is set to true, you can't modify anything in VerticalScroll or HorizontalScroll.  AutoScroll means AutoScroll; the control decides when scrollbars are visible, what the min/max is, etc. and you can't change a thing.
So if you want to customize the scrolling (e.g. hide scrollbars), you must set AutoScroll to false.

Looking at the source code for the ScrollableControl with Lutz Roeder's .NET Reflecter, you can see that if AutoScroll is set to true, it ignores your attempts to change property values within the VerticalScroll or HorizontalScroll properties such as MinValue, MaxValue, Visible etc.

#### Behavior Observations 2:

With AutoScroll set to false, you can change VerticalScroll.Minimum, VerticalScroll.Maximum, VerticalScroll.Visible values.
However, you cannot change VerticalScroll.Value!!!  Wtf!  If you set it to a non-zero value, it resets itself to zero.
Instead, you must set AutoScrollPosition = new Point( 0, desired_vertical_scroll_value );
And finally, SURPRISE, when you assign positive values, it flips them to negative values, so if you check AutoScrollPosition.X, it will be negative!  Assign it positive, it comes back negative.
So yeah, if you want custom scrolling, set AutoScroll to false.  Then set the VerticalScroll and HorizontalScroll properties (except Value).  Then to change the scroll value, you need to set AutoScrollPosition, even though you aren't using auto scrolling!  Finally, when you set the AutoScrollPosition, it will take on the opposite (i.e. negative) value that you assign to it, so if you want to retrieve the current AutoScrollPosition later, for example if you want to offset the scroll value by dragging the mouse to pan, then you need to remember to negate the value returned by AutoScrollPosition before reassigning it to AutoScrollPosition with some offset.  WOW.  Wtf.

One other thing, if you are trying to pan with the mouse, use the values of Cursor.Position rather than any mouse locations returned by the mouse events parameters.  Scrolling the control will cause the event parameter values to be offset as well, which will cause it to start firing mouse move events complete with undesired values.  Just use Cursor.Position, because it will use mouse screen coordinates as a fixed frame of reference, which is what you want when you're trying to pan/offset the scroll value.