# Hide ListBox Scrollbar & Synchronize Scrolling

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm using 3 ListBox Controls and I want to remove their Scrollbars, so they're appearance may looking *cleaner*.

I have it so when I select an item in any, it selects the same in the rest. Only problem is that I have no idea how to make them scroll together.
E.g., if I scrolled down in the first Listbox, the position of the other two should match the position of the the first one.

I'd also like to know how to remove the Scrollbar, since there is no property for this.

Comment: So, you have 3 ListBox Controls and only one has scrollbars? Otherwise, how do you scroll the first one? Do all contain the same objects? Otherwise, what do you *synchronize* in these ListBoxes? -- Depending on what you need to handle and how, you could hide the scrollbars, as in [Hiding the Scrollbar while allowing scrolling with the Mouse Wheel in a FlowLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67855814/7444103). Or create a new Custom Control and remove the `WS_VSCROLL = 0x00200000` style (in CreateParams)

Comment: @Jimi I want to have 0 scrollbars, or at second best, only one at the right, and scrolling syncs them all up.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of a ListBox stripped of its Vertical ScrollBar that can handle Mouse Wheel messages and scroll itself.
The Vertical ScrollBar is removed by default, unless the [ScrollAlwaysVisible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.scrollalwaysvisible) property is set to `true` or the custom public `VerticalScrollBar` property is set to `true`.

The LisBox is scrolled setting its [TopIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.topindex) property. There's a Min/Max check in WndProc where `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` is handled that ensures that the list is not scrolled beyond its limits.
It's kind of a *redundant* check, but may come in handy if you needs to be perform a more complex calculation to determine the current offset.

When the ListBox is scrolled, it raises the custom public `Scroll` event. You could create a custom EventArgs class to pass specific values to the Event Handler, if required. Here, I'm just synchronizing all ListBox Controls using the `TopIndex` property.

Note that the Mouse Wheel scrolls the ListBox by 1 Item, while also pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> sets the scroll to 3 Items. Modify this behavior as required.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[DesignerCategory("code")]
public class ListBoxEx : ListBox
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Scroll;

    private const int WS_VSCROLL = 0x200000;
    private const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A;
    private const int MK_SHIFT = 0x0004;
    private bool m_VerticalScrollBar = false;

    public ListBoxEx() { }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
        get {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            if (!ScrollAlwaysVisible && !m_VerticalScrollBar) {
                cp.Style &=~WS_VSCROLL;
            }
            return cp;
        }
    }

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool VerticalScrollBar {
        get => m_VerticalScrollBar;
        set {
            if (value != m_VerticalScrollBar) {
                m_VerticalScrollBar = value;
                RecreateHandle();
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        switch (m.Msg) {
            case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
                var wparm = m.WParam.ToInt64();
                int button = (short)wparm;
                int delta = (int)(wparm >> 16);
                int direction = Math.Sign(delta);
                int steps = button == MK_SHIFT ? 3 : 1;
                TopIndex = Math.Max(Math.Min(Items.Count - 1, TopIndex - (steps * direction)), 0);
                Scroll?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Add three instances of this Custom Control to a Form and subscribe to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the first one (for example). E.g.,

```
private void listBoxEx1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lb = (sender as ListBox);
    if (listBoxEx2.Items.Count > lb.SelectedIndex) {
        listBoxEx2.SelectedIndex = lb.SelectedIndex;
    }
    if (listBoxEx3.Items.Count > lb.SelectedIndex) {
        listBoxEx3.SelectedIndex = lb.SelectedIndex;
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to sync-scroll the three Controls, subscribe to the custom Scroll event of the first:

```
private void listBoxEx1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lb = sender as ListBox;
    listBoxEx2.TopIndex = lb.TopIndex;
    listBoxEx3.TopIndex = lb.TopIndex;
}
```

This is how it works:
<sub>The code sample also handles ListBox Controls with different number of Items</sub>

[image: ListBox No Vertical ScrollBar]

---

**Edit:**

**How to use:**
`ListBoxEx` is a Custom Control class.
To create this Control:

- Add a new `Class` file to the Project, name it `ListBoxEx`.
- Overwrite the class definition in that file with the class content you find here.
  Add on top the 2 `using` directives you find in this code.
- Build the Project.

Now, in the ToolBox, you can find the new ListBoxEx Control.
To replicate what is shown here:

- Drop 3 instances of it onto a Form.
- In the designer, select the first object (`listBoxEx1`).
- In the PropertyGrid, switch to the events (⚡) view. Find the `Scroll` and `SelectedIndexChanged` events and double-click each. It will create the event handlers for you.
- Copy the content of the event handler you find here inside the new event handlers just created.

**Or**, subscribe to the events in code:

- Copy the `listBoxEx1_Scroll` and `listBoxEx1_SelectedIndexChanged` handlers you find here (including their content) and paste them inside the Form that contains the ListBoxEx Controls.
- Add this to the Form Constructor, after `InitializeComponent()`, to subscribe to the `Scroll` and `SelectedIndexChanged` events of `listBoxEx1`:

  ```
    listBoxEx1.Scroll += this.listBoxEx1_Scroll;
    listBoxEx1.SelectedIndexChanged += this.listBoxEx1_SelectedIndexChanged;
  ```

Comment: how do I sub to the custom Scroll event, there is no event for this in events.. New to events im afraid

Comment: See the description in the Edit.