# How to scrollUp or down in panel with Mouse_Wheel Events without using Scrollbar Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollview, mouseevent, panel

Example:

I have a `Panel` or `flowLayoutpanel` so I want to scroll look into items without using scrollbar, instead I want to use MouseWheel

So I was wondering is there any way that you can scroll up or down in a panel or flowLayoutPanel

Without use `'Auto Scroll= true'` instead I want to moveViewPanel up or down when mouse scrolled.

If you get what I mean

These are some code that I used with but seemed not to work at all

--Sameple1

```
 void Panel2_mWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            //Get cursor position
            Point mousePoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

            //Change to the location of the form of this form
            mousePoint.Offset(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y);

            if (panel2.RectangleToScreen(panel2.DisplayRectangle).Contains(mousePoint))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Contain");
                panel2.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, panel2.VerticalScroll.Value - e.Delta);
            }
        }
```

--Sample2

```
 Panel.MouseEnter += C_MouseEnter;
  void Panel_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      c.Focus();
                
  }
```

--sample3

```
panel.MouseWheel += pn_MouseWheel;

private void pn_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
int deltaScroll = 10;

if (e.Delta > 0)
{

    if (pnlContain.VerticalScroll.Value - deltaScroll >= pnlContain.VerticalScroll.Minimum)
        pnlContain.VerticalScroll.Value -= deltaScroll;
    else
        pnlContain.VerticalScroll.Value = pnlContain.VerticalScroll.Minimum;
}
else
{
    if (pnlContain.VerticalScroll.Value + deltaScroll <= pnlContain.VerticalScroll.Maximum)
        pnlContain.VerticalScroll.Value += deltaScroll;
    else
        pnlContain.VerticalScroll.Value = pnlContain.VerticalScroll.Maximum;
}
```

--sample 4

```
panel_wheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     if(e.OldValue>e.NewValue)
     {
         //Scroll up Do stuff
     }
     else
     {
         //Scroll down Do stuff
     }

}
```

**Anyone help me please!!**

Comment: What does the debugger say? does the code enter the mousewheel event(s)?

Comment: @TaW yes the debugger working seem to work fine every function detected, but the problem is I still can't scroll  up or down in panel still!!

Comment: [Hiding the Scrollbar while allowing scrolling with the Mouse Wheel in a FlowLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67855814/7444103) -- Since your FlowLayoutPanel / Panel will contain child Controls, it may not receive messages that are directed to a child Control. That code use IMessageFilter to trap all messages of interest and then decides what to do: use it and then forward it to the destination or suppress it. -- The ScrollBars are just *hidden*.