# How to check in winform what panel is being clicked on?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, function, winforms

I have two panels in my winform. **panel1** is blue, and **panel2** is red. I would like to know if there is a function that tells what panel i clicked on, otherwise then using private void panel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs{} function. Thank you, here is my code:

```
private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Control control = this.GetChildAtPoint(e.Location);
            if (control is Panel)
            {
                Panel clickedPanel = (Panel)control;
                if (clickedPanel.Name.Equals("panel1"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("you clicked on blue panel");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("you clicked on red panel");
                }
            }
        }
```

This function doesn't work, and I don't know what to do.

I tried many functions, but i can't search for any "universal" function, that tells what object i clicked on.

Comment: Usually you would attach click handlers to the panels (or whatever component) and get notifications directly from them. In fact, I don't believe the one you use here fires at all when the user clicks on a component within the form.

Comment: A form can preprocess key events before they are handled by a control but i don't think there is such thing for mouse events. SO controls handle the events by themself and you need to handle all of there MouseClick Events. You might want to think about implementing an [IMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) to preprocess Windows Message before reaching controls and beeing translated into events.

Comment: @Ralf so there is no function in winform that tells what object is being clicked on?

Comment: A windows message like a click are send to the control at the mouse location (that is already an OS thing not directly connected to the winforms implementation)  so the form never sees them and it also has typically no need to see them. So no there is no such thing that i know of.

Comment: See `case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:` in the PrefilterMesage method of the IMessageFilter implementation here: [Hiding the Scrollbar while allowing scrolling with the Mouse Wheel in a FlowLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67855814/7444103). It's applied to a FlowLayoutPanel, but you can apply it to a Form, to know what Control is going to be clicked (before the Control itself knows it)

Comment: As long as you add the corresponding event and bind it to the corresponding space, you can do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have attached a function for the form click event handler; this will handle mouse click events on the form and not on the panel. If you can view the Panels on the designer, then you can double-click each and the IDE will auto generate the method that will handle the mouse click event for each Panel.

Alternatively, you can add the event handlers for each Panel in the constructor of the form like below:

```
public class MyForm: Form{

public MyForm(){
     InitializeComponent();
     //register the event listeners for the panels
     panel1.MouseClick += panel1_Clicked;
     panel2.MouseClick += panel2_Clicked;
  }
  //implement the methods
   private void panel1_Clicked(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
      //handle the click for panel1
   }
   private void panel2_Clicked(object sender, 
 MouseEventArgs e){
      //handle the click for panel2
   } 
}
```